# What may be difference between two php variable showing same result after echo?

Tags: php, variables

I have two php variable that showing same result after echo it. But if compare them using if condition that time it is not actual same.

I am elaborating my question using below code
`<?php echo $first.'<br>'.$one;?>`
Showing same result but

```
<?php if($first == $one){echo "Both are same";}else{echo "Both are different"}?>
```

Showing result Both are different

Comment: What is the type and value of your variables. Try var_dump($first, $one).

Comment: If your variables are string, try trimming them before comparing, it might be some spaces are being added. 
<?php if(trim($first) == trim($one)){echo "Both are same";}else{echo "Both are different"}?>

Answer (score 1):

try to use var_dump() ,for print this variables,and maybe you will see difference.
Because when you use echo you print html,for example  you can have 2 string like `$one = '<i>1</i>'` and `$second = '1'`,and  when you use echo you will see 1 1,but there are different

Comment: My var_dump($first) showing output string(12) and var_dump($one) showing string(8). So how can I make both equal?

Comment: If you need to get integer value from that string, try to use  trim() function for delete whitespace, i dunno wit what i can help you, i need more details. :)

Comment: Basically string data stored in that variable. So could I make both equal?